# Access Denied Exception while writing email Windows 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

```
private async Task<StorageFile> GetCsvFile()
        {
            var localFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
            var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("NRBcatalogue.csv", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            String rk = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < k1.Count; i++)
            {
                rk += k1[i] + "\n";   
            }
            await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, rk);
            return file;
        }

        private async void AppBarButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
            email.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("brk27.007@gmail.com"));
            email.Subject = "NRB Catalogue";
            var file = await GetCsvFile(); //Error occured here
            email.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file.Name, file));
            await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email);
        }
```

> The Error Details are: 
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll.
>   An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: Does your application have permission to access the documents library?

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to access a location that you don't have permission  `var localFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;`

This is valid exception because you can't access `DocumentsLibrary` location from you windows phone app. This location is only available for `Windows store app`. You can use other location but before using make sure that you have added this location as capability in the app’s manifest. For reference check [**This Link**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx#accessing_additional_locations).

So have to chose other location that your app can access. e.g LocalFolder , IsolatedStorage etc. For Localfolder just change your accessing folder code by below code.

```
 var localFolder =  Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

Hope it solve your problem. cheers :)